# Fetching data in small units instead of fetching at a time

Tags: java, mysql, jquery-plugins, struts2

I'm currently working on a Struts 2 application with Spring as backend with MySQL database.
Right now fetching 1000+ rows on page load.
I'm using tablesorter jquery plugin for displaying the results,sorting on click and pagination purpose.
But the page is taking lot of time to load and also it hangs in IE !!
Is there any easier way to do this like fetching required data from database as and when the user makes the selection like fetch first 10 rows,sorting data,etc.
Any ideas to make the application work faster are welcome !!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't tell from the docs if the plugin supported server-side paging or not, but that'd be one thing to consider. It was unclear if its [paging plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html) had any options for this.

Does the plugin's example with a thousand students crash under the same circumstance?

Comment: I would suggest using [dataTables](http://datatables.net) and its server-side option. I love this plugin, provides endless features and its free